# $E$ bounded above, show that there is a sequence $(a_n) \subset E$ such that $a_n \to \sup E$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $E$ be an infinite set of real numbers which is bounded above. Show that there exists a sequence $( a_n ) \subset E$ such that $\lim a_n = \sup E$ if $\sup E \not \in E$.

My attempt:

Let $(a_n)\subset E$ such that it converges to some $L$ such that $L\not\in E$. Let $L=\sup(E)$. This implies that $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $\sup(E)$ and that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n)= L = \sup(E)$.

Comment: "Let $(a_n)$ ..." How do you know such a sequence exists? How do you know such a sequence exists which converges to $\sup(E)$? You've just assumed what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Basically, every time you say the word "Let" you are making an assertion which needs to be based in logic. Particularly odd is that you say "Let $L=\sup(E)$." That's like proving $2+2=3$ by saying "Let $S=2+2$. Let $S=3$."

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you are asking. But anyway, since $E$ is bounded above, $\sup E<\infty $. Denote it $\ell$. By definition,
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists a\in E: \ell-\varepsilon<a<\ell.$$
How can you transform this expression to get a sequence $(a_n)\subset E$ that converge to $\ell$ ?

Comment: My attempt to answer your question.... We say that a sequence a_n converges to L iff its eventually epsilon-close to L for every epsilon>0.

Comment: based on what you said, can we imply that epsilon is greater than |a-L| so lim(an) = L = supE. Sup(E) is not an element of E because it is less than infinity and E contains infinite elements.

Comment: it implies that $$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\exists a_n\in E: \ell-\frac{1}{n}<a_n<\ell,$$ and thus, $(a_n)$ is a sequence of $E$ that converge to $\ell=\sup E$, what prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by definition of supremum, for each $n\ge1$ there exists an element $y\in E$ such that $y>\sup E-\frac1n$.